# Laravel Creating default object from empty value when creating an Eloquent object

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to save an object to the database for a game I'm building on a website, but I keep getting this error:

```
Creating default object from empty value
```

Here's the code I'm using:

```
    foreach( $input['items'] as $key=>$itemText ){
        $item = ($input['itemIDs'][$key] === 'NA') ? new GameItem() : GameItem::find($input['itemIDs'][$key]);
        // if updating this item, check that it is assigned to this game
        if( !is_null($item->game_id) && $item->game_id != $game->id ){ continue; }
        $item->game_id = $game->id;
        $item->item = $itemText;
        $item->answer = $input['answers'][$key];
        $item->save();
    }
```

The error occurs at the if statement. I tried commenting it out, and then the error occurred at the $item->game_id = $game->id; line.

I've var_dumped both $item and $game, and both are valid Eloquent objects. I even var_dumped the result of the if statement with no problems, so I'm at a loss as to what's happening.

I just noticed if I do

```
var_dump($item->toArray()); die();
```

right before the $item->save(); line, it doesn't throw any errors and shows me the array just fine.

What could be the problem then? I suppose it has to do with saving the item, but I don't understand it at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following line:

```
$item = ($input['itemIDs'][$key] === 'NA') ? new GameItem() : GameItem::find($input['itemIDs'][$key]);
```

Always doesn't return a `GameItem` object so when you try to use a `property` on `NULL` value then this error appears. So you should always check if the `$item` is not `NULL` using something like this:

```
if( !is_null($item) && $item->game_id != $game->id ) { continue; }
```

Instead of this (At first make sure `$item` is not `NULL` before you use `$item->game_id`):

```
if( !is_null($item->game_id) && $item->game_id != $game->id ){ continue; }
```

Comment: Thanks. I just figured out my problem, and this wasn't actually it, but it's true that the way I was doing it could have resulted in an error in other circumstances. I actually swapped out !is_null with empty().

Comment: Welcome and +1 because you deleted it but undone the action again :-)